# Cant access certificates in X509Store from asp.net core 2.1 with thumbprints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, x509certificate2, certificate-store

I have strange problem when accessing X509Store from IIS. I can't look them up.
If I access both the rp cert and ca cert from powershell both are there,

dir cert: -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Thumbprint -like "*thumprintstring*" }

I have checked that the thumbprints don't have a hidden char in the beginning of thumbprint
I have set that the certificates are exportable when I install them
I have for the moment set it accessable for everyone(its a certificate to a test server) in certficate
store

This is code I use

```
                StoreLocation location = certificateConfig.UseCurrentUserStoreLocation ? StoreLocation.CurrentUser : StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
 
                using (var clientCertStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, location))
                {
                    clientCertStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                    //Search for the client cert
                    X509Certificate2 rpCert = GetCertByThumbprint(clientCertStore, certificateConfig.RpCertThumbprint);
                    if (rpCert == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("No rp cert found for specified thumbprint #" + certificateConfig.RpCertThumbprint +"# "+location);
                    }
                    ClientCertificates.Add(rpCert);
                }
<snip>
        private X509Certificate2 GetCertByThumbprint(X509Store certStore, string thumbprint)
        {
            var certs = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

            return certs.Count > 0 ? certs[0] : null;
        }
```

The rpcert is always null whatever i try.
Do I need another way to open up the store from IIS?
Any ideas or suggestions?  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you verified that `thumbprint.Length` is 40, and only contains valid hexadecimal characters?  (I don't remember if casing matters, but if it does what it wants is uppercase, since that's what cert.Thumbprint uses)

Comment: And make sure that you are looking in right store location.

Comment: Running on IIS means the code is executed under another user account, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 So clearly it won't be able to go to the same certificate store.

Comment: @LexLi It seems that certificate storage outside of IIS is the same with one shown in IIS manager(or rather a subset of it). I did a test and when I added one of the outside it shows up on the IIS Manager certificate store. Also gave universal rights to read the certificates so that  trap is handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not what I expected. The config read from enviromentvariables that had been deleted so they didnt show in enviromentvariables and the server had not been restarted. And the deleted ones had most likely the bad character infront of the thumbprint.
Restarting iis doesn't solve this since the network service account doesnt reread these when already loggedon.

Follow up question: Is possible to relogin in network service account without restarting the server?

Comment: How is certificateConfig defined in your code? How are your environment variables set? Please show this part of the code. Usually the certificate settings are set in the config file.

Comment: @BruceZhang This is not project specific, From microsoft docs  
1. ChainedConfigurationProvider : Adds an existing IConfiguration as a source. In the default configuration case, add...  
2. appsettings.json using the JSON configuration provider.  
3. appsettings.Environment.json using the JSON configuration provider.   
4. App secrets when the app runs in the Development environment.  
5. Environment variables using the Environment Variables configuration provider.  
..